# Iterate over a NSSet - SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsset

I am starting to look at CoreData and have two entities. These form a many to many relationship between Player:

[image]

and Team:

[image]

I am trying to iterate through the players of a team using a ForEach inside a list but I can't seem to get it to work. The code I have been trying is below. Any other solutions I try I get errors such as 'Value of type NSObject has no member name'

```
struct PlayersView: View{
    var team: Team
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(team.people! as Set), id: \.self){ player in
                    Text("\(player.name)" ) //Error on this line
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I think I need to change the player type back to the Player Object but I am not sure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following (compiled with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
ForEach(Array(team.people as? Set<Player> ?? []), id: \.self){ player in
    Text("\(player.name ?? "")" )
}
```

*Caution: try to avoid force unwrapping for optionals, very often it will result in run-time crash.*

Answer (score 8):

While [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65705280/7337547) that [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) suggested works, there is an issue. `ForEach` is deprived of reactive updates when displaying a collection of values backed by `NSSet`. If `people` change, `ForEach` will not be able to pick up that change and refresh itself right away.

This is because `NSSet` is a class and SwiftUI can only reactively update properties that are structures, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919526/7337547).

I believe the better architecture would be to use fetch request to get all the players associated with a given team. That fetch request would have to be configured inside of view’s initializer method, with `NSPredicate` that specifies that we want players for a certain team. If you have a *many-to-many* relationship, use **ANY** operator in your `NSPredicate`.

```swift
struct PlayersView: View {
    let team: Team
    
    @FetchRequest private var people: FetchedResults<Player>
    
    init(team: Team) {
        self.team = team
        
        _people = FetchRequest(
            entity: Player.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Player.name, ascending: true)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "team == %@", team)
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(people) { player in
                    Text("\(player.name ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can plug the results of that fetch request right into `ForEach` and don’t have to do any type casting. Even better, SwiftUI can now automatically update contents of that `ForEach` based on changes that it notices.

Comment: Why the hell is this not the accepted answer!!